# Squarify treemap — How to add legend for rectangles that are too small?

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, treemap, squarify

My treemap has a rectangle that's too small to fit its label, so I need to move the labels out of the treemap into a legend. I'm using `norm_x` because I'm trying to simulate a thermometer-style plot. Here's a look at the code and the awkward label:

```
sizes = [30, 15, 3]
        
labels = [
    'Largest Block\n(30 units)',
    'Second Largest Block\n(15 units)',
    'Small Block\n(3 units)'
]     
            
tmap = squarify.plot(
    sizes,
    label=labels,
    alpha=.7,
    norm_x=10,
)

tmap.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    
plt.legend(labels)
```

Which produces:

[image]

When I add `plt.legend(labels)` (and drop the labels from the squarify call) I get this legend with only one label:

[image]

So I just need to find a way to add all the labels from the plot into the legend. The matplotlib documentation suggests I may need to add three artists into the `plt.legend()` call, but I'm not sure how to do that in this case. Also, if you have a better idea than creating a legend to resolve this issue, that might be an even better answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectangles are stored together in a `BarContainer`. By default, matplotlib supposes one legend label for the complete container.  To have a legend label for each individual rectangle, you can pass the `BarContainer` as handles to `plt.legend()`.

The sample code below explicitly assigns colors, as the default colors can be bit hard to distinguish.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import squarify

sizes = [30, 15, 3]
labels = ['Largest Block\n(30 units)', 'Second Largest Block\n(15 units)', 'Small Block\n(3 units)']

ax = squarify.plot(sizes, alpha=.7, norm_x=10, color=plt.cm.Set2.colors)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import squarify

sizes = [30, 15, 3]
labels = ['Largest Block\n(30 units)', 'Second Largest Block\n(15 units)', 'Small Block\n(3 units)']

ax = squarify.plot(sizes, norm_x=10, color=plt.cm.Set2.colors)
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.legend(handles=ax.containers[0], labels=labels)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

PS: To have the legend in the same order as the displayed rectangles you could reverse the y-axis (`ax.invert_yaxis()`) or reverse the lists of handles and labels (`plt.legend(handles=ax.containers[0][::-1], labels=labels[::-1])`).

Here is another example, annotating the largest rectangles inside the plot and showing the smallest in the legend:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import squarify
import numpy as np

labels = [55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]
sizes = [f * f for f in labels]
num_labels_in_legend = 5

ax = squarify.plot(sizes, label=labels[:-num_labels_in_legend], color=plt.cm.plasma(np.linspace(0, 1, len(labels))),
                   ec='black', norm_x=144, norm_y=89, text_kwargs={'color': 'white', 'size': 18})
ax.axis('off')
ax.invert_xaxis()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.legend(handles=ax.containers[0][:-num_labels_in_legend - 1:-1], labels=labels[:-num_labels_in_legend - 1:-1],
           handlelength=1, handleheight=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: second example]

Here is an idea to calculate the number of labels to be shown in the legend. For example when the summed area of the small rectangles is less than 5% of the total area:

```py
num_labels_in_legend = np.count_nonzero(np.cumsum(sizes) / sum(sizes) > 0.95)
```

Or just the number of rectangles smaller than 2% of the total area:

```py
num_labels_in_legend = np.count_nonzero(np.array(sizes) / sum(sizes) < 0.02)
```

Comment: Great answer; I was just about to add the `handles=ax.containers[0][::-1]` addition for order. Do you think there's a way to have the number of labels moved to legend determined automatically rather than hardcoding it in? (The plot I'm making is for an automatic script, so I won't be able to change it from use to use.)

Comment: I just added a possible formula.